# How can I create a click and drag to change the width of an object with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, touch

I have an object that I want to change the width of when you click on it and drag right or left.  Adding to the width or taking away from it as you move the mouse (or finger).

```
<style>
    #changeMe {width:300px; height: 200px;}
</style>

<div id="changeMe">
    Some Content
</div>

<script>
    $('#changeMe').mousedown(function(){
        //Some Code?????
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is track the x co-ords of the mouse. If greater than they were before, increase size, if lower, decrease the size.

Not tested but the below should be inspiration.

```
var oldXPos = 0;
var isDragging = false;

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    if (isDragging)
    {
        var difference = event.pageX - oldXPos;
        // Do something with this value, will be an int related to how much it's moved
        // ie $('#changeMe').css.width += difference;
    }
    oldXPos = event.pageX;
});

$('#changeMe').mousedown(function() {
    isDragging = true;
})
$('#changeMe').mouseup(function() {
    isDragging = false;
})
```

Comment: Awesome!  That does exactly what I wanted!  Thank you so much!  One more question for you.  How would I bind this to a touch and drag event?

Comment: How do you mean? If you mean the mouse literally touches the div and it chamges the size, replace "mousedown" with "mouseover" and "mouseup" with "mouseout". That'll give you more of a hover effect, while the mouse is on the div it'll respond to the left and right changes, without needing to be clicked.

Comment: No I means on a touch device like an iPad or tablet.  I was able to figure it out and I answered it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283649/how-do-i-make-the-width-of-and-element-change-when-a-touch-and-drag-is-detected/18346345#18346345)

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `resizable({})` effect .

```
$('#changeMe').resizable({});
```

You can look at this article

[Resizable](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4aac15/jquery-ui-demystified-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
     $('.testSubject').resizable();
 });
```

or

```
#changeMe {width:300px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black;}

<body>
<div id="changeMe">
    Some Content
</div>
</body>

  $('#changeMe').resizable({});
```

Or

```
 $(function(){

            $('img[src*=small]').toggle(
                function() {
                  $(this).attr('src',
                    $(this).attr('src').replace(/small/,'medium'));
                },
                function() {
                  $(this).attr('src',
                    $(this).attr('src').replace(/medium/,'large'));
                },
                function() {
                  $(this).attr('src',
                    $(this).attr('src').replace(/large/,'small'));
                }
            );

          });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, that you want to be able to dynamically increase/decrease the size of the object as it moves along the x-axis, I recommend that you use $('#changeMe').[offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) inside the jQuery UI [drag](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag) event.

You can create a formula that you want to use based on an initial offset, and the new offset to size your container by $('#changeMe').css({ width: X, height: Y });, and insert whatever your X and Y values are in pixels.

Edited for further elaboration with code:

```
var initX = 0;
var initW = 0;
$('#changeMe').draggable({
    start: function() {
        initX = $(this).offset().left;
        initW = $(this).width();
    },
    drag: function() {
        var deltaX = initX - $(this).offset().left;
        $(this).css({ width: initW + deltaX });
    }
});
```

If you used that as your base, it's a very nice and simple solution for your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I have looked into offset() and as far as I can see it can give you / change the top, bottom, left, and right based on another object.  I don't know if that would work.  When a user clicks and drags the mouse/finger 16px to the left I want the objects width to minus 16px as the users drags.  Would I be able to do this with offset?

Comment: Yes.  You can do that using offset().  Offset returns the top/left with regard to the document.  You also have the height/width of the object.  It is very simple to compute the width and the drag event makes this computation dynamic.